# Style function image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've currently got this setup for a javascript function. How can I make some css styles apply to the image?

Here is my code:

```
function iCall1() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "i1.png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

I don't want to place the image source in my html document for diffrent reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a class:

```js
function iCall1() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "http://placehold.it/400x150";
    img.className = "myClass";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

iCall1();
```

```css
.myClass {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

Or by adding an ID:

```js
function iCall1() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "http://placehold.it/400x150";
    img.setAttribute("id", "myID");
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

iCall1();
```

```css
#myID {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked out great!